# Unit Testing on Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, electron

I have a simple Electron app with no frameworks (React, Angular). I am trying to incorporate units tests with Mocha but I have problems understanding some of the concepts. I need to access the HTML that is being loaded since all my components ultimately depend on it (I have a small, custom, MVC structure).

I am reading examples like

```
describe("List", function(){ 
  beforeEach(() => { 
    this.list = document.getElementById("ul"); 
  }); 
  it("updates from a given collection", () => { 
    expect(this.list.querySelectorAll("li").length).toBe(2); 
  }); 
}
```

Where is the `document` taken from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In usual `Mocha` tests, `document` is just an empty object, just to pass tests which rely on document events or API. In your case, i think you need to look at something like Spectron testing framework, to be able to get instance of app window and access to real document of your application: https://electronjs.org/spectron